# What is the best way to create XML for Stored Procedure Output

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xslt, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns few thousand records. I need to apply XSL to output of this SP. What would be the best way to do that

1. Read data in dataset, use XmlDataDocument and apply XSL
2. Output XML from SP and apply XSL on that

For 2, I am worried that XML size will be too big and C# code reading it will timeout. Please suggest.

Comment: How big can the XML-sets in each of these records actually be?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `SqlXmlCommand` type from the namespace `Microsoft.Data.SqlXml`.

From msdn [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171950.aspx):

```
SqlXmlCommand cmd = new SqlXmlCommand(ConnString);
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 20 FirstName, LastName FROM Person.Contact FOR XML AUTO";
cmd.XslPath = "MyXSL.xsl";
cmd.RootTag = "root";
...etc
```

If you're worried about timing out just set a larger timeout on your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

We use a similar approach on our platform. But we do not apply the XSL directly on the stored procedure as we use MS SQL Server Express and it does not allow to apply the XSL's. At least that is what I have found when looking for this particular subject, a superior version of MSSQL Server is needed for such transformation.

The stored procedure that outputs the XML is big and filthy (but runs smoothly) and we have no issues reading back the results. Couple of seconds for each request at most, usually around couple thousands rows as result and joining several tables. Using VS2010 and VB.Net with Telerik components.